# Bootstrap Popover - Showing at the bootom

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to show a popover when a user selects text on a webpage - The code I am using is the following to display popover

**HTML**

```
<div id="popover-content" style="display:none">
    <button class="pop-sync">Share</button>
    <button class="pop-delete">Save</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var div = null;
    function popNow() {
        var selection = window.getSelection(), 
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0), 
            rect = range.getBoundingClientRect(); 

        if (rect.width > 0) {
            if (div) {
                div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
            }
            div = document.createElement('div'); // create div to show popover on          
            document.body.appendChild(div); // append div with selected text
            var popOverSettings = {
                placement: 'bottom',
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                div: '[rel="popover"]', //setting div for popover
                content: function () {
                    return $('#popover-content').html();
                }
            }
            $('body').popover(popOverSettings);
        }
    }
    window.onmouseup = popNow;
</script>
```

It works but it displays popover at the bottom of the page instead of at the bottom of selected text where I have clearly defined `div`.

**Screenshot is the following** 
[image]

The popover is showing after the footer, how can I make this to show at the bottom of selected text?

Any ideas

Cheers

Comment: which version of BS?

Comment: the bootstrap version is v3.0.0

Comment: placement: 'bottom' isn't this the culprit?

Comment: I think guys the issue is in `$('body').popover(popOverSettings);` its setting popover to the body of the page - @Satya I am not sure

Comment: have you tried removing div: '[rel="popover"]',  and changing placement:'bottom' to placement: 'right'

Comment: @Satya where i switched to right and removed `[rel` it is not showing anything now - No errors in console

Comment: @aliusman Can you share a working fiddle?

Comment: its not even triggering in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (not sure if its a good method ;) )

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $(".popover").css({"top": evt.clientY + 10, "left": evt.clientX - 100});
      }, 500);
```

after

```
$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
```

You need to set the top position of popover to the selected text position, not the position of the text containing element.

You also need to pass event

```
function popNow(evt) {...}
```

Play [here](https://www.bootply.com/Qc5YhPk4AM)

Comment: Yeah you are right, but this Didn't work, i tried on `div` as well , but still no luck